# Problems with collision detection with my pong game

Tags: processing, pong

This is my first Java program I have ever made and I was trying to make an ai that predicts the location of the ball, that works fine but. Sometimes when the ball hits the very corner of the paddle it goes through the paddle. I know this is because it hits the speed is reversed twice for some reason

```
if ((yball > ypaddle) && (yball  < ypaddle+120) && ((xball == xpaddle+39) || (xball < xpaddle+39) && (xball > 0))){

   if(failsafe == 0){
   xSpeed*= -1;
   playerHit.play();
   failsafe+=1;
  
   counter = 0;
   if(speed == maxSpeed){
     float nothing = 0;
   } 
   else{
    if (xSpeed > 0){
    xSpeed += increment;
 }
   
    else{
    xSpeed -= increment;
    }
    }
    if (ySpeed < 0){
      ySpeed -= increment; 
      
    }
    else{
    ySpeed += increment;
   }
   }
```

These are the dimensions of the paddle `rect(0, 50, 20, 100);`

Comment: Are you using integers or floats for your positions (the x/y coordinates)? Also, can the ball's speed go up to 20 and more?

Comment: Your conditions are a but confusing at the x side (why not (xball<=xpadlle+39) and I question whether condition 5 (xball>0) is correct given that the y condition suggests it might be (xball>xpaddle). A rectangle is describable using only 4 terms having ((y<Q)||(y==Q)) is the same as saying (y<=Q)